# How to make integer index of unique values in Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question regarding Numpy arrays (the answer should include them). I want to create and array where each element will be mapped into a specific integer. Here is the code I got until now:

```
array1 = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'parrot', 'parrot', 'dog'])
array2 = (np.unique(array1))
for index, key in enumerate(array2):
     print(np.where(array1 == key, index+1, 0))
```

The output now is:

```
[1 0 0 0 1]
[0 2 0 0 0]
[0 0 3 3 0]
```

But I want it to be just

```
[1 2 3 3 1]
```

Comment: Note that you usually want to avoid iterating over a NumPy array, and use it's vectorised approach (including broadcasting where necessary).

Comment: Depending on the final goal, you could actually use [scikit-learn's OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html).

Comment: Not sure the title matches the problem you want solved.  How about 'How to make integer index of unique values in Numpy array?'

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too picky about the exact value of the integer (just that they are unique and match a string one-to-one):

```
array1 = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'parrot', 'parrot', 'dog'])
result = np.unique(array1, return_inverse=True)[1] + 1
```

(The `+ 1` is there so that it matches your result, since you also have `index+1` in the original code.)